# Site Deployment Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, deployment

I have developed a site, took a back up on the development site. I have created a empty site on the live environment. I have restored the blank site from the backup.

I need to change some parameters of the webpart. could anybody suggest me what those list of parameters as I have the following error.

```
Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Windows SharePoint Services-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backup/restore in SharePoint doesn't include custom solutions (wsp file) which means you need to deploy them manually using stsadm tool. See example below:

```
stsadm -o deploysolution -name webparts.wsp -allowgacdeployment -immediate -url http://localhost
```

Comment: thank you. But My Development manager has done this before by just changing some ID. the way he has done is He created a just a normal custom list on the server and he copied the id( I don't remember them now, if I have then I would have done it, but he is not in the office today.) for the newly developed webpart. I am sure there is way but I forgot it..

Comment: I got it now. We need to change the default value of restored site the *.cmp file with the desitination site. It works fine..